# Is it possible to get all the tasks I assigned to other users in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I know that Work Management Service allows aggregating all the tasks assigned to me in my user profile. But is there an out-of-the-box way to get all the tasks I created or modified for other users (assigned tasks to them)?

I can see the only way so far: CSWP with query for Task content type with fields CreatedBy or ModifiedBy that equal to me.